# IF and Switch activities not available in the pipeline Activities pane

Tags: azure-synapse

Using Synapse ADF, IF and Switch activities are not available in the pipeline Activities pane

[image: IF and Switch activities not showing up]

Microsoft says they should be there [If Condition activity - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity)

Is the list of activities configurable ? How to add activities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest these activities so `If` and `Switch` will not appear on the menu when you are inside an `If` or a `Switch`.  You also cannot nest For Each activities.  Simply come back up to the top level of your pipeline and you will see the activities.

If you have more complex logic, think about using the logical functions in the [expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#logical-functions) like `and` and `or`, or using like a Stored Procedure, Databricks Notebook, Azure Synapse Notebook, etc